# How to get data from Web.API to a Windows application when the desired Controller requires user authorization?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

There are a lot of examples about getting data from Web.Api by Windows appliaction, but all what I have seen are using Controlles that not require user authentication.
In my case I need to get data from a windows application, but the method of the Web.Api I need to call is a method of a controller that requires user athentication (the controller is decorated by `[Authorize]` attribute).

One from the straight forward examples about getting data I found here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/mobile-clients/calling-web-api-from-a-windows-phone-8-application

but there is nothig about user there:

```
  public void LoadData()
        {
            if (this.IsDataLoaded == false)
            {
                this.Items.Clear();
                this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID = "0", LineOne = "Please Wait...", LineTwo = "Please wait while the catalog is downloaded from the server.", LineThree = null });
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
                webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadCatalogCompleted);
                webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(apiUrl));
            }
        }

        private void webClient_DownloadCatalogCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Items.Clear();
                if (e.Result != null)
                {
                    var books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BookDetails[]>(e.Result);
                    int id = 0;
                    foreach (BookDetails book in books)
                    {
                        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel()
                        {
                            ID = (id++).ToString(),
                            LineOne = book.Title,
                            LineTwo = book.Author,
                            LineThree = book.Description.Replace("\n", " ")
                        });
                    }
                    this.IsDataLoaded = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel()
                {
                    ID = "0",
                    LineOne = "An Error Occurred",
                    LineTwo = String.Format("The following exception occured: {0}", ex.Message),
                    LineThree = String.Format("Additional inner exception information: {0}", ex.InnerException.Message)
                });
            }
        }
```

how to complete the LoadData method so I could get result after being authenticated through Google? (Microsoft?)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly: because you need to authorize your request. In your application (WebAPI) create a folder called "Attributes" add a function to check whenever your parameter is correct. For example:

```
public class AuthWebsiteAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{       
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var auth = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;

        if (auth == null)
            return false;

        var param = auth.Parameter;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
            return false;

        // now check if the parameter is correct, for example ask your database if the // user email exists or something

        return company != null;
    }
}
```

No your attribute is named "AuthWebsite" and you use it in your controller. For example:

```
  [AuthWebsite, RoutePrefix("api/basket")]
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
/// if you are here then you are already authenticated
}
```

But how do you authenticate? well it's simple, you need add to your request a parameter: "Authorization:". I'm using base64 encoding so this is how it would look in fiddler:

```
 Authorization: Basic MOdzIEFyWm==
```

Those characters is my password and my username.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but your authorization spec is a Basis authorithation policy given on IIS to a particular site. But what I am asking for, is an authentication through 3rd party Authentication provides like Google, Microsoft, Facebook etc.